# how to get custom attribute value from bestseller products collections in block magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-collection

Here I am trying to get custom attribute value from bestseller products collections magento 2??

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class BestSeller extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
   protected $_collectionFactory;
   protected $_storeManager;   
   protected $_productloader;  
   protected $categoryFactory; 
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
       array $data = []
   ) { 
       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
       $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

    public function getBestSellerData(){

        $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                    ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                    ->setPeriod('month') //you can add period daily,yearly
                    ->setPageSize(8);            

        return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;

    }


}
```

> In phtml file i am trying like this

```
$bestCollection = $block->getBestSellerData();
foreach($bestCollection as $bproduct){
$ProductType = $bproduct->getData('type_product');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Block file**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class BestSeller extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
   protected $_collectionFactory;
   protected $_storeManager;   
   protected $_productloader;  
   protected $categoryFactory; 
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
       \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
       array $data = []
   ) { 
       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
       $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

    public function getBestSellerData(){

        $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                    ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                    ->setPeriod('month') //you can add period daily,yearly
                    ->setPageSize(8);            

        return $bestSellerProdcutCollection;

    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

**phtml file**

```
$bestCollection = $block->getBestSellerData();
foreach($bestCollection as $bproduct){
$p = $block->getLoadProduct($bproduct->getId());
$ProductType = $p->getData('type_product');
}
```